# Find symbolic links

Tags: find, symbolic-link

I'm awared that `find -L` or `find -type l` would find all symbolic links on a given path.

But I'm trying to find all symbolic links that points to my `foo` folder.

Any tips?

Comment: Except that's how it's done.

Comment: @Ignacio Sorry, changed the point of question. Could you re-read?

Answer (score 0):

I found how to do that.

```
find / -lname /path/to/foo/folder
```

Will give me every symlink pointing to that folder.

Although `find` mess up with `/proc` folder, but that's life.

**EDIT**: Also, it's also possible to:

Find the inode number of the file and then search for all files with the same inode number:

```
$ ls -i foo.txt
41525360 foo.txt

$ find . -follow -inum 41525360
Alternatively, try the lname option of find, but this won't work if you have relative symlinks e.g. a -> ../foo.txt

$ find . -lname /path/to/foo.txt
```

ps: took from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184849/symbolic-link-find-all-files-that-link-to-this-file)